# Converting c++ copyTo to python

Tags: python, c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to convert the following OpenCV C++ to Python:

Cpp:

```
//step1
Mat edges;
adaptiveThreshold(vertical, edges, 255, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 3, -2);
imshow("edges", edges);
// Step 2
Mat kernel = Mat::ones(2, 2, CV_8UC1);
dilate(edges, edges, kernel);
imshow("dilate", edges);
// Step 3
Mat smooth;
vertical.copyTo(smooth);
// Step 4
blur(smooth, smooth, Size(2, 2));
// Step 5
smooth.copyTo(vertical, edges);
// Show final result
imshow("smooth", vertical);
```

I'm not sure how to handle converting step3 to python. I have done step1 and 2 as below in python

```
#step1
edges = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(vertical,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,3,-2)

#step2 
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), dtype = "uint8")
dilated = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv::Mat::copyTo` in your case simply makes a copy of the image.  In fact, how you're using it is equivalent to using `cv::Mat::clone` as you aren't specifying  a mask.  As such in Python, use the [`numpy.copy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) method as OpenCV uses NumPy arrays as the main datatype:

```
# Step #3
smooth = vertical.copy()
```

For Step #5, you are now copying based on a mask.  I've already answered how to do that in a previous post of mine: [Equivalent of copyTo in Python OpenCV bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572887/equivalent-of-copyto-in-python-opencv-bindings).  You are looking at the second situation where the matrix you are copying to has already been allocated and only want to copy over the values that are non-zero in the mask.  However, for the sake of completeness I'll put it here for you.

You essentially want to modify `vertical` using `smooth` but only copying over the elements of `smooth` that are defined by the non-zero elements in `edges`.  You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find the non-zero row and column locations and use these to copy over the right values between `smooth` and `vertical`.  It also looks like you have a grayscale image so this makes it even simpler:

```
# Step #5
(rows, cols) = np.where(edges != 0)
vertical[rows, cols] = smooth[rows, cols]
```

Comment: Thank you! this makes sense now. Also, what you've explained for step 5 is immensely helpful. In a larger context, I'm trying to convert a c++ code into python. I've done it but I suspect it is incorrect because the results aren't the same. I've posted a separate question that I would really appreciate your input on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453892/converting-c-opencv-to-python

Comment: You are most welcome. I do have to sleep now but I will examine your question when I wake up.