# How to put an image or video in the same position of a contour line, python + opencv

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

i have the position of the contour, how can i put an image or video at the same position of the contour and on the other hand as i can reduce the size of both.
my code is

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Iniciar camara
captura = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

#Caputrar una imagen y convertirla a hsv
_, imagen = captura.read()
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img=cv2.imread('calibresult.png')
#Guardamos el rango de colores hsv (azules)
bajos = np.array([100,65,75], dtype=np.uint8)
altos = np.array([130, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)

#Crear una mascara que detecte los colores
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, bajos, altos)

#Filtrar el ruido con un CLOSE seguido de un OPEN
kernel = np.ones((6,6),np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

#Difuminamos la mascara para suavizar los contornos y aplicamos filtro canny
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (5, 5), 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(mask,1,2)

#Si el area blanca de la mascara es superior a 500px, no se trata de ruido
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
i = 0
for extension in areas:
    if extension > 600:
        actual = contours[i]#position of countour
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(actual,0.05*cv2.arcLength(actual,True),True)
        if len(approx)==3:
            cv2.drawContours(imagen,[actual],0,(0,0,255),2)
            cv2.drawContours(mask,[actual],0,(0,0,255),2)

        i = i+1

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('Camara', imagen)
tecla = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
if tecla == 27:
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

"actual" is the position of the contour
for example, i want the code to register the outline of a rectangle and in the same position of the outline place an image, all in real time,the position would be with respect to the center of the contour

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean by "how can i put an image or video at the same position of the contour". Can you further clarify this? Do you have a visual representation of your desired output?

Comment: for example, i want the code to register the outline of a rectangle and in the same position of the outline place an image, all in real time,the position would be with respect to the center of the contour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the excellent answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572887/equivalent-of-copyto-in-python-opencv-bindings):

```
dst = cv2.imread("destination.jpg", -1)
src = cv2.imread("source.jpg", -1)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 130, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

im2,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(dst, contour, -1, (0,0,255), thickness = 2)

locs = np.where(binary != 0) # Get the non-zero mask locations

# Case #1 - Other image is grayscale and source image is colour
if len(dst.shape) == 3 and len(src.shape) != 3:
    dst[locs[0], locs[1]] = src[locs[0], locs[1], None]
# Case #2 - Both images are colour or grayscale
elif (len(dst.shape) == 3 and len(src.shape) == 3) or (len(dst.shape) == 1 and len(src.shape) == 1):
    dst[locs[0], locs[1]] = src[locs[0], locs[1]]
# Otherwise, we can't do this
else:
    raise Exception("Incompatible input and output dimensions")
```

[image]