# How to add transparent background in video?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

```
import os
from turtle import back
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"

import numpy as np
import cv2
from glob import glob
from tqdm import tqdm
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.utils import CustomObjectScope
from metrics import dice_loss, dice_coef, iou
import moviepy.editor
from moviepy.editor import *

""" Global parameters """
H = 512
W = 512

""" Creating a directory """
def create_dir(path):
   if not os.path.exists(path):
      os.makedirs(path)

   if __name__ == "__main__":
   """ Seeding """
   np.random.seed(42)
   tf.random.set_seed(42)

   """ Directory for storing files """
   create_dir("processed_videos")
   create_dir("frames")

   """ Loading model: DeepLabV3+ """
   with CustomObjectScope({'iou': iou, 'dice_coef': dice_coef, 'dice_loss': dice_loss}):
      model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5")
# model.summary()

   """ Video Path """
   video_path = "videos/in1.mp4"

   # """Extracting the audio from video"""
   # # Replace the parameter with the location of the video
   # video = moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip(video_path)
   # audio = video.audio
   # # Replace the parameter with the location along with filename
   # audio.write_audiofile("/Users/sotsys207/Downloads/Remove-Background-from-Video-using-TensorFlow-main/audio/sample.mp3")

   """ Reading frames """
   vs = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
   _, frame = vs.read()
   h, w, _ = frame.shape
   vs.release()

   fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
   out = cv2.VideoWriter(f'processed_videos/output.avi', fourcc, 30, (w, h), True)

   cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
   idx = 0
   while True:
      ret, frame = cap.read()
      if ret == False:
         cap.release()
         out.release()
         break

      h, w, _ = frame.shape
      ori_frame = frame
      frame = cv2.resize(frame, (W, H))
      frame = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)
      frame = frame / 255.0

      mask = model.predict(frame)[0]
      mask = cv2.resize(mask, (w, h))
      mask = mask > 0.5
      mask = mask.astype(np.float32)
      mask = np.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1)

      photo_mask = mask
      background_mask = np.abs(1-mask)

      masked_frame = ori_frame * photo_mask
      print(masked_frame.shape)
      masked_frame = np.expand_dims(masked_frame, axis=0)

      background_mask = np.concatenate([background_mask, background_mask, background_mask, background_mask], axis=-3)
      # print(background_mask)
      background_mask = background_mask * [255, 255, 255, 0]
      print(background_mask.shape)
      final_frame = masked_frame + background_mask
      final_frame = final_frame.astype(np.uint8)
      # print(final_frame)

      cv2.imwrite(f"frames/{idx}.png", final_frame)
      idx += 1

      out.write(final_frame)
```

I am trying to add transparent background but i don't know how to do it can any one help me to do it.

I have tried it but it gives me error

```
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step
(1280, 720, 3)
(5120, 720, 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sotsys207/Downloads/Remove-Background-from-Video-using-TensorFlow-main/run.py", line 90, in <module>
    final_frame = masked_frame + background_mask
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,1280,720,3) (5120,720,4)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "transparent"? Is that what the alpha channel is for? I suspect if you're using the alpha channel, then all you need to do is concatenate the background_mask on to the end of the masked_frame. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365126/combine-2-images-with-mask the answers here might help with your array manipulations.

Comment: Hello @Pam,
Actually i didn't get the answer you have sent. What i mean by transparent is i am removing the background from image from this 
background_mask = background_mask * [0,0,0] I am getting the black background but i want transparent bg.
background_mask = background_mask * [255, 255, 255, 0] so i have tried this but it is not working

Comment: What I mean is that I don't think you have to multiply the RGB channels by the background mask. In your code, you concatenate the background mask 4 times. You just need to concatenate the (single channel) background mask to the masked_frame so that it forms an alpha channel.