# Insert a masked region of an image in another (HDR) via OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have two images and a mask. The first image `(im1)` is my source image, the second `(im2)` is the image whose region need to be inserted in `im1` and the third image `(mask)` contains 1's in the region that needs to be pasted. All images have the same size `(H*W*3)`. It should be noted that `im1` is HDR( .exr format). 
After reading  via OpenCV

```
im1 = .imread(im1, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)[:,:,0:3]
im2 = ...
mask = ...
```

how can I transfer the masked region(contained in `mask` array) of image `im2` without any loss of information (no change apart from masked region) in `im1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would use OpenCV's [`copyTo()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=clone#mat-copyto) method which will copy an image or masked image region from one `Mat` to another. 
Unfortunately, this functionality is not available in the OpenCV Python bindings.

There is a Python workaround for this function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41573727/6436977) though which you could use instead.